# Installing Node.js (and npm) on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, installation

I had some issues trying to install Node on Windows 10 and found the solution.

The error was as follows:

> C:\Users\Stephan>npm
>   Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Stephan\AppData\Roaming\npm'

The solution is below.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Edit:**
It seems like new installers do not have this problem anymore, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42731621/3978539) by [Parag Meshram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158207/parag-meshram) as my answer is likely obsolete now.

**Original answer:**

Follow these steps, closely:

- http://nodejs.org/download/ download the 64 bits version, 32 is for hipsters
- Install it anywhere you want, by default:  `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
- Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables
- Select `PATH` and choose to edit it.

If the PATH variable is `empty`, change it to this: `C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs`

If the PATH variable already contains `C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\AppData\Roaming\npm`, append the following right after: `;C:\Program Files\nodejs`

If the PATH variable contains information, but nothing regarding npm, append this to the end of the PATH: `;C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Now that the PATH variable is set correctly, you will still encounter errors. Manually go into the AppData directory and you will find that there is no npm directory inside Roaming. Manually create this directory.

Re-start the command prompt and npm will now work.

Comment: @captainrad so far I have not had any trouble, but I cannot be sure about release before Dec 7

Comment: @captainrad It worked when I copied files in C:\Program Files\nodejs to C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME HERE}\AppData\Roaming\npm on Windows 10

Comment: @DannyG Thanks for your edit, but please only edit when it improves the answer. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing for more on this subject.

Comment: Just as a heads up, Stephan, the recent edit/rollback sparked a (not bad) [Meta conversation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310646/edit-a-post-that-can-possibly-contain-offensive-unnecesary-text) it might be worth your time to look at. It might give you some more context for why DannyG edited your answer.

Comment: I tried to reinstall and it's working now. Path must be in "User variables for {user login name}" listbox, not system variables.

Comment: "... is for hipsters" ;-)

Comment: October 2017, this answer still applies but the npm folder in Roaming was created in my case but contains no files

Answer (score 68):

go to http://nodejs.org/

and hit the button that says "Download For ..."

This'll download the .msi (or .pkg for mac) which will do all the installation and paths for you, unlike the selected answer.

Comment: Mind explaining why the accepted answer did not work for you?

Comment: The accepted answer required me to manually enter the paths which is not required if you run the installer (.msi).

Comment: Then either the installer has been updated to automatically do this in the past few weeks, or you just got lucky on your system :-) I do doubt this, however.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  If you are on Windows the default install works             ( .msi ) ... thanks @foreyez

Comment: Definitely the best answer - works fine on windows 10 for me too

Comment: That sounds sensible but ends up creating a mess (if you do this as admin).  I explain in my answer below why you should tell the installer to put it in %appdata% instead.

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer as Its just one step solution rather then @StephanBijzitter solution which requires me to first browse their download directory searching for correct versions which I don't know about(not familiar with nodejs).

Comment: The installer does not work on Windows 10 at all. It only creates a path to installation folder not roaming.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the answer from @StephanBijzitter I would use the following `PATH` variables instead:

```
%appdata%\npm
%ProgramFiles%\nodejs
```

So your new `PATH` would look like:

```
[existing stuff];%appdata%\npm;%ProgramFiles%\nodejs
```

This has the advantage of neiter being user dependent nor 32/64bit dependent.

Comment: This is great if you've installed it in the default location, but please bear in mind that if you did not, this will only serve to clutter up the PATH variable.

Answer (score 11):

New installers (.msi downloaded from https://nodejs.org) have "Add to PATH" option. By default it is selected. Make sure that you leave it checked.

[image: Add to PATH]

Comment: Well finally :-)

Comment: Strange, I used this installer and they were definitely checked. I still had to add the nodejs folder in the path variables

Answer (score 3):

Everything should be installed in %appdata% (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming), not 'program files'.

Here's why...

The default MSI installer puts Node and the NPM that comes with it in 'program files' and adds this to the system path, but it sets the user path for NPM to %appdata% (c:\users[username]\appdata\roaming) since the user doesn't have sufficient priveleges to write to 'program files'.

This creates a mess as all modules go into %appdata%, and when you upgrade NPM itself - which NPM themselves recommend you do right away - you end up with two copies: the original still in 'program files' since NPM can't erase that, and the new one inn %appdata%.

Even worse, if you mistakenly perform NPM operations as admin (much easier on Windows then on *nix) then it will operate on the 'program files' copy of NPM node_modules.  Potentially a real mess.

So, when you run the installer simply point it to %appdata% and avoid all this.

And note that this isn't anything wierd - it’s what would happen if you ran the installer with just user priveleges.

Answer (score 2):

You should run the installer as administrator.

1. Run the command prompt as administrator
2. cd directory where msi file is present
3. launch msi file by typing the name in the command prompt
4. You should be happy to see all node commands work from new command prompt shell

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what helped we was turning of my anti virus protection for like 10 minutes while node installed and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have to modify the AppData could be:

1. Node.js couldn't handle path longer then 256 characters, windows tend to have very long PATH.
2. If you are login from a corporate environment, your AppData might be on the server - that won't work. The npm directory must be in your local drive.

Even after doing that, the latest LTE (4.4.4) still have problem with Windows 10, it worked for a little while then whenever I try to:

```
$ npm install _some_package_ --global
```

Node throw the "FATAL ERROR CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory" error. Still try to find a solution to that problem.

The only thing I find works is to run Vagrant or Virtual box, then run the Linux command line (must matching the path) which is quite a messy solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to delete the nodejs folder in \program files and then when I went to install through the msi it worked. Seemed like when I uninstalled Node it didnt actually delete this file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after trying everything on this post unsuccessfully, I just had to restart.
So if you haven't tried restarting the computer after the installation, try it.

> Restart your computer after installation