# Many errors with NPM install on windows 10

Tags: node.js

I recently upgraded my OS to Windows 10. I've been trying many solutions to these problems for days. I even followed the instructions that are posted in this link [Installing Node.js (and NPM) on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10) , but it didnt work. I also tried searching for possible solutions on [GITHUB npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen), still no luck. I can't start my work because of these errors. I need help please. Thanks in advance[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: I had an issue with a module requiring compilation too, I force updated npm and node-gyp to make it work (I still use a v0.12 nodejs) but it seems you are already up to date. You should post your `npm-debug.log` somewhere. You can also try this: https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/

Comment: I completely reformatted my PC  to windows 10 again. And reinstalled GIT and NodeJS, It worked. Maybe upgrading from Win7 to Win10 will give you these errors.