# socket (10106) error node

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to use any of the NodeJS or NPM commands but I always got the following error:

> socket: (10106) The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.

I'm running Windows 10, I tried to re-installed the nodejs again but still the same.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution to my problem:
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/asp-net-state-service-wont-start-t3422497.html

This sounds like a Winsock problem, not a problem with Nodejs itself. You
can reset your Winsock installation to setup defaults by following the
instructions from this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811259

(The short version of this is to use `netsh winsock reset` from a command
prompt.)

I reset my winsock installation and rebooted.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344046/5026490

I think there is an issue using Windows 10. Perhaps try the early versions 7 or 8.1 or please try that link above.

Comment: I tried to install the 64 version of the nodejs but still the same issue