# Permission Denied in console, NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have just downloaded NodeJs on my Windows 10 PC and, after reload, if I type in the command prompt of NodeJs (I have tryed also in the Git Shell) "node" or "npm" it say "Permission Denied".

I'm sorry for any grammar error but I am not italian :)

Thank you for answer!

Comment: Just downloaded? Or also installed? What exactly is the complete error message?

Comment: Windows + Node locally = Headaches

Comment: @OliverQueen, that's just an opinion. @Flybeer, have you tried right-click the Node cmd shortcut and `Run as administrator`?

Comment: Yes, i have tryed but it still doesn't work

Comment: @KirillSlatin Nodejs has a known Python dependency bug that they have not fixed yet.

Comment: I have python installed on the comptuer

Comment: You probably didn't add Node to your PATH variable

Comment: I've got Node 0.10.35 (x64) on my Windows 8.1 and no python. All installed from Node bundle. And I don't experience any troubles

Comment: @KirillSlatin - not everyone builds from someone else

Comment: @OliverQueen how i can do it?

Comment: Verify this is not your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27864253/2020002

Comment: I have do it but it still doesnt work!

Comment: http://imgur.com/rPl7m4p

Comment: @OliverQueen what I have to do?

Comment: @Flybeer - try running the command `nodejs`

Comment: If I click node.js come th error "You cant access at this file"