# 'Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args' npm error after reinstalling node.js in Windows10

Tags: node.js, windows, npm-install

I downloaded Node.js (4.4.5 LTS) from the [official site](https://nodejs.org/en/)  and installed it to update node in my Windows10, and found npm not working(node worked).I uninstalled node by installing it in "remove" mode, and then reinstalled, but the error persisted. The error upon npm -v is as follows:
```
    module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> 

(C:\Users\<my-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\np
    m\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:6:23)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

`Per suggestions from [this link][2] I have edited the PATH of Environmental Variables (in both User and System) to include:`

    C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm

 `and`

    C:\Program Files\nodejs 

`With 'which npm' it produced:`

    /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm

`With 'whereis npm' it showed:`

    npm: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm 
    /cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm.cmd

`With 'which node' I got`

    /c/Program Files/nodejs/node
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

link2: [Installing Node.js (and npm) on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) it is necessary to delete node and node_modules from 'local' directories in order to remove node (and npm) completely. Thinking I only need to remove old npm relics to solve the error about 'Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args', I tried  [deleting npm and npm-cache](https://origin1tech.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/clearing-nodes-npm-cache/) inside AppData/Roaming directory manually, followed by reinstalling node in 'repair' mode, and (after restart) finally npm works.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after a brew update. I'm using nvm so I just reconfigured nvm to use my version with `nvm use vx.x.x`