# Installing NativeScript CLi

Tags: angularjs, nativescript

I am trying to get started working with NativeScript but I am running into various issues installing it. I have tried various workarounds from the web but I keep on running into more so I thought I would post it here.

I am running windows 10 on my laptop. The error I am currently getting is:

```
..\src\fibers.cc(727): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modu
les\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(731): warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'size_t', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\fib
ers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\fibers.cc(738): warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modu
les\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\coroutine.cc(110): warning C4552: '!' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect [C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\f
ibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
..\src\coroutine.cc(186): warning C4267: 'argument' : conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data [C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\
node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
  coro.c
  win_delay_load_hook.c
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib' [C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:204:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v6.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\Aazir\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
```

Answer (score 4):

it says; nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command

maybe you want to reinstall your nodejs;

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344046/816658

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have actually already done the things in that link and set the path properly

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem was just that I had the latest version of Node installed 6.2.2 which is not yet supported by NativeScript, I just uninstalled it and installed a previous version and it worked fine