# npm -v Command shows Error like -g is not recognized as an internal or external com mand

Tags: node.js, npm

i am new in node.js and i am trying to install node.js  in my Window 8 pc. node.js  installed  successfully but when is  type command npm -v it's show Error Something like...

C:\windows\system32>npm -v

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external com
mand,
operable program or batch file.
5.6.0

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjqZ8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, this means npm is either not installed, or else the user trying to run it doesn't have rights to execute a program on the path in question.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to add `node` and `npm` to paths manually. Here is an instruction: [Installing Node.js (and npm) on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10)