# Why does react-native uinstall after running react-native command to install a package?

Tags: react-native, npm

I installed react-native globally and confirmed installation on Windows 10. Then I ran react-native command in PowerShell to install materials-kit and vector-icons. The installation of these packages failed and the directory is no longer considered a react-native project directory. I have to reinstall react-native as a result.

How can I install materials-kit and vector-icons without causing the system to uninstall react-native?

**Steps Taken**

I ran the below code in PowerShell. **Please Note:** I also used MS Visual Code and the Terminal in MS Studio Code.

**Input**

npm install -g react-native-cli

react-native -version

**Output**

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.59.5

**Additional Input**

npm install --save react-native-material-kit react-native-vector-icons

react-native -version

**Additional Ouput**

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory

I was expecting these two react-native packages to be installed. Did not happen.

**Extra Information: Error Code Snippet**

...

npm ERR! code EPERM

npm ERR! errno -4048

npm ERR! syscall rename

...

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),

npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a project with the `react-native-cli` then add your required packages there.
so the steps should be like this:

1. install the cli tool as you've done it very well.

   `npm install -g react-native-cli`
2. create a project (you need to provide a name for it).

   `react-native init *<project_name>*`
3. change your current directory to the created project

   `cd *<project_name>*`
4. install your favorite packages.

   `npm install --save react-native-material-kit react-native-vector-icons`
5. run the react-native packager for your target platform (ios or android)

   `react-native run-ios`

or

```
`react-native run-android`
```

*happy coding!*

Comment: Thank you. However, this is what I did in the beginning. I apologise for not mentioning I typed react-native init crm in the above post. I was in the crm directory when I tried to install material-kit and vector-icons.

Comment: obviously, your problem relates to installing node on your windows. you may consider using windows terminal instead and make sure your $PATH variable includes node installation directory. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10) might help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the program by starting again with no active react-native directory.

**1. decided to use Expo to expedite the react-native application set-up process**

npm install expo-cli --global

**2. initialised new project && changed directory**

expo init cra

cd cra

**3. installed the react-native material-kit and vector-icons packages individually using yarn instead of npm**

yarn add react-native-material-kit

yarn add react-native-vector-icons

**4.confirmed installation**

**Input**

react-native -version

**Output**

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.57.1