# Error trying to install node.js(v15.3.0) on Windows 10 from nodejs.org

Tags: node.js, windows, installation

When I try to install node.js from the installer that I have downloaded from website nodejs.org I get error message "An error occurred while attempting to create the directory: C:\Users\User\Appdata\Roaming"

Answer (score 1):

I have listed the possible causes and solutions. Please try them.

Causes:

- Permissions or user profile issues can cause this issue.
- If Windows Defender thinks the installer is unfriendly it may prevent the creation of files and folders.

Solution:
First, check to see if Windows Defender is preventing the creation of the folder. Open Windows Defender Security Center and navigate to the following:

- Click Virus & threat protection.
- Click Virus & threat protection settings.
- Scroll down to Controlled folder access and temporarily switch to
  the OFF position.
- Try the installation again.

If none of these work, visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10) link where a similar question was asked.