# Problem while installing ejs-mate ejs-mate

Tags: node.js, templates, backend, ejs, web-development-server

[image: ##]

here is a screenshot of the error message shown. I am using a Windows 10 machine and the node version installed is 14.

Comment: It seems node is not installed on your system. Can you paste the o/p of node -v?

Comment: The error means that the program `node` is not in your search path.

Comment: node -v  v14.15.4

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that `node` is either not installed or not in your search path (`$PATH`).

Comment: how do I add it?

Comment: What OS?  On Debian/Ubuntu it would be `apt install nodejs` as root (possible via sudo).  See also https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-install-nodejs

Comment: I using windows and git bash

Comment: Yep, so the link I gave you has a download link https://nodejs.org/en/download/ with a Windows installer.

Comment: I have installed node and checked the path in my env variables, it's there. But I'm getting the  same error again

Comment: What is the path of node.exe and what is `echo $PATH`?

Comment: this link will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10