# Unable to open X display | puppeteer - nodeJs | Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

i have an issue when i execute my Js file.
here is my script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = "https://www.cdiscount.com/informatique/ecrans-informatiques/ecran-pc-gamer-incurve-msi-optix-mag241cvsfr-2/f-10732-9s63ea21t049.html?idOffre=345385285";

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
   
})()
```

in my terminal: **reject(new Error([
^
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[189:189:0427/181045.185226:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1393)] Unable to open X display.**

please help me, I have already entered a lot of command lines in the terminal but nothing helps.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow ! Which browser are you trying to launch ? Which version ? How do you launch your script ? Are you using a virtual machine ?

Comment: Hello, i'm trying to launch chromium with pepputeer, I'm using node v16.0, I'm on windows 10 with Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you need to see the browser ? This problem seems related to the fact that you use WSL and it can't find a DISPLAY to display the browser. If you run your script in a Windows terminal instead of WSL it should be easier.

Comment: yes i would like to see the browser for a test, when I use windows Powershell terminal the command lines doesn't work.. I don't understand where the problem is from, is it my computer ? Puppeteer ? WSL ?

Comment: You can install nodejs on Windows. If ```node``` is not found maybe you have to configure your ```PATH``` environment variable, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27344046/4726998 Try with a simple HelloWorld  script first then try to run your script.

Comment: Yes I install node on Windows and it's working now.. maybe It's not usable with WSL...