# How to use Code Runner extension for JavaScript on VS code

Tags: javascript, vscode-code-runner

I'm new to programming and I just started learning JS. I tried running my first code via 'code runner' on Visual Studio Code but it wasn't giving me the output. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNwEy.jpg)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @charlietfl And worse, that's not even an image of code, but an image of a computer monitor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `NodeJS` first in order to run the JavaScript on your machine. You can download it [here](https://nodejs.org/en/). Then, you should make sure that Node path is added. After that restart VS Code and run it again.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I add the Node path?

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: Windows 10 pro.

Comment: Here is the question about installing NodeJS on windows and adding it to path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10